# Get width height of remote image from url

Tags: javascript, image, height, width

So the alert gives undefined values for the width and height. I think the w and h values of the image from the img.onload calculation is not being passed to the values to return, or it may be returning w and h **before** the onload calculates them:

```
function getMeta(url){
 var w; var h;
 var img=new Image;
 img.src=url;
 img.onload=function(){w=this.width; h=this.height;};
 return {w:w,h:h}    
}

// "http://snook.ca/files/mootools_83_snookca.png" //1024x678
// "http://shijitht.files.wordpress.com/2010/08/github.png" //128x128

var end = getMeta("http://shijitht.files.wordpress.com/2010/08/github.png");
var w = end.w;
var h = end.h;
alert(w+'width'+h+'height');
```

How can I have the alert show the correct width and height?

http://jsfiddle.net/YtqXk/

Comment: The reason it's not working is because at the point when you `return` your width and height values they are not yet known. You need to deal with the result _inside_ the `onload` callback. You should probably make the callback function a second argument to your `getMeta` function.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

## Get image size with JavaScript

In order to read the data from an image you'll need to make sure it's first loaded. Here's a callback-based approach and two promise-based solutions:

### Callback

```js
const getMeta = (url, cb) => {
  const img = new Image();
  img.onload = () => cb(null, img);
  img.onerror = (err) => cb(err);
  img.src = url;
};

// Use like:
getMeta("https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCWYU.jpg", (err, img) => {
  console.log(img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight);
});
```

### Using the **`load` Event listener** (Promise):

```js
const getMeta = (url) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => resolve(img);
    img.onerror = (err) => reject(err);
    img.src = url;
  });

// Usage example: 
;(async() => {
  const img = await getMeta('https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCWYU.jpg');
  console.dir(img.naturalHeight + ' ' + img.naturalWidth);
})();
```

### Using [HTMLImageElement.decode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/decode) (Promise)

```js
const getMeta = async (url) => {
  const img = new Image();
  img.src = url;
  await img.decode();  
  return img
};

// Usage example:
getMeta('https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCWYU.jpg').then(img => {
  console.dir(img.naturalHeight +' '+ img.naturalWidth);
});
```

- MDN Docs: [HTMLImageElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement)

Comment: Since the width and height are not being returned, how can I have them returned to use outside the function?

Comment: @Wonka not without calling some function inside the `.load` function --- or a setInterval, cause while your code is readed and executed, the image is still loading: Interval will check till the image is loaded and clear it self like in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/SN2t6/1/

Comment: @Wonka look at here for **call a function as soon the image is loaded :** http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/SN2t6/4/

Comment: Note that the width and height come back as `0` for SVG images in IE11

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, a code from the jQuery section throws the error: `Uncaught TypeError: url.indexOf is not a function`. I think a little mistake creep into it, namely `img` attribute and listener are landed in the same object. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61844018/5589126)

Comment: This comes back with a CORS error if not on the same origin - even with `img.crossOrigin=true` added.  Is there a way to change the MIME type of this request or otherwise add headers to a pure JPG request?

Answer (score 35):

Just pass a callback as argument like this:

```js
function getMeta(url, callback) {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = url;
    img.onload = function() { callback(this.width, this.height); }
}
getMeta(
  "http://snook.ca/files/mootools_83_snookca.png",
  (width, height) => { alert(width + 'px ' + height + 'px') }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is help me a lot.

Comment: Note that the width and height come back as `0` for SVG images in IE11

Answer (score 28):

## ES6

Using `async/await` you can do below `getMeta` function in sequence-like way and you can use it as follows (which is almost identical to code in your question (I add `await` keyword and change variable `end` to `img`, and change `var` to `let` keyword). You need to run `getMeta` by `await` only from `async` function (run).

```js
function getMeta(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let img = new Image();
        img.onload = () => resolve(img);
        img.onerror = () => reject();
        img.src = url;
    });
}

async function run() {

  let img = await getMeta("http://shijitht.files.wordpress.com/2010/08/github.png");

  let w = img.width;
  let h = img.height; 

  size.innerText = `width=${w}px, height=${h}px`;
  size.appendChild(img);
}

run();
```

```html
<div id="size" />
```

### Rxjs

```js
const { race, fromEvent, map, mergeMap, of } = rxjs;

function getMeta(url) {
    return of(url).pipe(
        mergeMap((path) => {
            const img = new Image();
            let load = fromEvent(img, 'load').pipe(map(_=> img))
            let error = fromEvent(img, 'error').pipe(mergeMap((err) => throwError(() => err)));
            img.src = path;
            
            return race(load, error);
        })
    );
}


let url = "http://shijitht.files.wordpress.com/2010/08/github.png";

getMeta(url).subscribe(img=> { 
  let w = img.width;
  let h = img.height; 

  size.innerText = `width=${w}px, height=${h}px`;
  size.appendChild(img);
}, e=> console.log('Load error'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.5.2/rxjs.umd.min.js" integrity="sha512-wBEi/LQM8Pi08xK2jwHJNCiHchHnfcJao0XVQvkTGc91Q/yvC/6q0xPf+qQr54SlG8yRbRCA8QDYrA98+0H+hg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="size" />
```

Comment: Thank you. I used Promise.all() to get all values at once.

Answer (score 13):

The `w` and `h` variables in `img.onload` function are not in the same scope with those in the `getMeta()` function. One way to do it, is as follows:

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/ppanagi/28UES/2/

```
function getMeta(varA, varB) {
    if (typeof varB !== 'undefined') {
       alert(varA + ' width ' + varB + ' height');
    } else {
       var img = new Image();
       img.src = varA;
       img.onload = getMeta(this.width, this.height);
    }
}


getMeta("http://snook.ca/files/mootools_83_snookca.png");
```

Comment: Thanks, this works as intended, just takes a bit too long to get the info

Comment: This solution will not work if the image has not already been stored in the browser's cache. You must accept a callback function in getMeta that will be called when the onload event fires (http://jsfiddle.net/28UES/)

Comment: @Zack hmmm.. Since the width and height are not being returned, how can I have them returned to use outside the function?

Comment: @Wonka updated my answer. As soon as you define a callback function you can pass it the variables and manipulate them in the callback function.

Comment: @Zack I see the update, which resolves the cache issue. But can you show how to access the width and height outside the function. I need the function to return values outside of itself.

Comment: @Wonka It's not possible to know the width and height of an image until after it has been downloaded. This occurs asynchronously (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691301/async-or-sync-when-we-set-the-src-property-of-the-image-object), so the getMeta function cannot return the dimensions directly. The usual workaround is to pass a callback function to getMeta that does something useful with the dimensions after the image has been loaded.

Comment: Any code outside the getMeta() function will be called before the dimensions of the image are available. Therefore, as Ferri points out, you need to use a callback function for the onload event of the image.

Comment: this is [**recursive function**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) (function which call itself)

Answer (score 0):

**Get image size with jQuery**
(depending on which formatting method is more suitable for your preferences):

```js
function getMeta(url){
    $('<img/>',{
        src: url,
        on: {
            load: (e) => {
                console.log('image size:', $(e.target).width(), $(e.target).height());
            },
        }
    });
}
```

or

```js
function getMeta(url){
    $('<img/>',{
        src: url,
    }).on({
        load: (e) => {
            console.log('image size:', $(e.target).width(), $(e.target).height());
        },
    });
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You will can try [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-size-from-url).

```
import getImageSize from 'image-size-from-url';

const {width, height} = await getImageSize('URL');
```