# Javascript - tell width/height of image that haven't been implemented on the webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, height, width

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript - Function to return width/height of remote image from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442712/javascript-function-to-return-width-height-of-remote-image-from-url)

Is it possible to get width and height by just knowing the images location with js? The actual picture isn't loaded onto the DOM. I have been trying this with jQuery but with no luck yet.

```
var img = $('<img>').attr('src', 'images/logo.png');
console.log($(img).width());
```

returns 0.

Comment: Listen to the `load` event of the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the image doesn't need to be in the DOM.

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
        console.log(this.width);
    };
img.src="images/logo.png";
```

But you have to load it before knowing its dimensions

(note the src after the onload function)

here is a jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/fGUyz/2/

#NotMrDownVoter

Comment: This would appear not to work: http://jsfiddle.net/CPTgn/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sorry, use "this" instead of "$(img)" http://jsfiddle.net/fGUyz/2/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the image must be in the DOM for the width/height to be calculated.

You can cheat this by appending it to the page, but positioning it well off the screen, like this:

```
.offscreen {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}
```

```js
var $img = $('<img>', {
    'src': 'images/logo.png',
    'class': 'offscreen'
}).appendTo('body');
console.log($img.width());
$img.remove() // if required...
```

Comment: Also, wrap this logic inside [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) instead of `ready`; this makes sure that the images have been loaded in the first place so it can measure them. Demo here: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/#entry-examples #NotMrDownVoter

Comment: Actually, @Dr.Molle pointed me into the right direction,

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately as Rory McCrossan has already suggested, when using JQuery you must add the element to the DOM before **any** of the width() or height() functions will return anything other than 0.

Having a hidden element will also return width/height of 0.