# Fetch absolute URL image size without request

Tags: node.js, fetch, image-size

I am trying to get the image size of an image that I have as an absolute url. So far I have been using [image-size](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-size). On production however we face an issue with those external domains, as all the requests to the outside network are being filtered.

Is someone aware of a different option to get the size of the images, given only an absolute url?

**P.S:** size = width and height of the image, not the file size

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you mean resolution or file size?

Comment: Resolution. I will edit the question. Thanks.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442712/get-width-height-of-remote-image-from-url?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) answer uses JavaScript’s Image object and a callback function.