# How to get the remote located image size in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

i'm getting the remote URL's of images from a text file how to read the size(dimensions) of that image in react js.

Comment: have code samples? you have method for reading, and need wrap for use in react?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442712/get-width-height-of-remote-image-from-url

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get width height of remote image from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442712/get-width-height-of-remote-image-from-url)