# How can I to read width, height, filesize of image in s3?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In laravel 8 uploading image to AWS S3 and I keep url in db table(I set visibility= 'public',
so I can show image in my browser by this saved url. Also I need to get width, height, filesize
of this file. When I use Storage in local I use Intervention\Image library with methods :

```
$file_width  = Image::make($image_path)->width();
$file_height = Image::make($image_path)->height();
$file_size   = Image::make($image_path)->filesize();
```

where $image_path - is path under my Storage.

With Object URL property my uploaded image has properties
S3 URI looking like

```
   s3://app-s3/subdir/filepath.jpg
```

and Amazon Resource Name (ARN) :

```
arn:aws:s3:::app-s3/app-s3/subdir/filepath/31fzgzXsVTL.jpg
```

How can I to read width, height, filesize of image in s3 ?

**MODIFIED BLOCK :**
Reading at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#file-metadata link
example code:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
$size = Storage::size('file.jpg');
```

I try with get size with ‘s3’ driver:

```
$image_size = Storage::disk('s3')->size($cloud_url);
```

I got error :

```
File not found at path: https:/app-s3.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/app-s3/subdir/filepath/31fzgzxsvtl.jpg
```

As $cloud_url is common url, not path ...
From the docs looks like 'file.jpg' is PATH of the image in Storage directory. But I am not sure...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use the S3 public URL to open the image. You can get that using [`Storage::url`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#file-urls) and will result in a URL like e.g. `https://app-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/subdir/filepath.jpg` or something like this

Comment: filesize can be obtained from header, height and width can be obtained via js property from the image url

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#file-metadata

Comment: Please look at MODIFIED BLOCK

Comment: @bhucho, please3 ref to such example

Comment: You can send a head request (this will be fastest and lightest as it has no body just headers) or if you want the image then you can send a get request the header `content-length` would have the filesize, for height width see this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/11442712/9471283