# How to overlay Canvas with a Canvas dynamically?

Tags: javascript, css, html

i have a canvas dynamically written with no id assigned to it. How can i overlay image on the first canvas (out of multiple canvas) via JS ?

```
<canvas  width="240" height="297">

<canvas id = "image_to_Overlay" width = "800" height = "500"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the **1st canvas of the DOM** using plain javascript you can use the good old function `document.getElementsByTagName()`. Then do what you want with it.

Probably it would be safer matching even on other attributes - such as class name - just to avoid getting the wrong canvas (jquery selectors would work great).

BTW the following should work

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      var image = new Image(); 
      image.onload = function (){//react on image download completed
        //you can get the 1st canvas of the DOM accessing the array of canvas 
        var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0]; 
        //then draw on it as needed 
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d'); 

        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
      };
      //load image
      image.src = "http://i.imgur.com/ITWfejd.png";
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas  width="240" height="297"></canvas>

    <canvas id = "image_to_Overlay" width = "800" height = "500"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. I dont see the image drawing on the canvas.    
var image = new Image(); 
image.src = "https://i.imgur.com/ITWfejd.png";

//you can get the 1st canvas of the DOM accessing the array of canvas
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];

//then draw on it as needed
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.drawImage(image,1000,1000);

Comment: That's because `image.src='...'` returns immediately: the image download is asynchronous.
If you call it early, then you have to wait for the image to be available, i.e. using  an event listener, like `image.onload=...`
It really depends on your logic.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691301/async-or-sync-when-we-set-the-src-property-of-the-image-object

Comment: I've expanded the example with full html document and `onload` function. Again, you can move it where needed depending on your specific needs. Keep in mind that
1) the image src must be set after the onload event listener function has been attached
2) the canvas should be available at that time.

Comment: My requirement is to put the image of glass on top of the below chart , which is not working http://bl.ocks.org/MohamedZaki/326752ae3c1beed530242417fc6b20bb

Comment: Should I see a canvas on that document? I see only svg

Comment: Project is available here https://github.com/SAP/openui5-charting-custom-controls . The renderer function in /webapp/control/C3JSControl.js has the canvas to be used.